# How many distinct "sentences" can be formed from the word PORPOISE?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For example, PORPOISE is a possible one-word sentence, and E S I O P R O P is a possible eight-word sentence. I have figured out how many distinct arrangements of the word there are, which is easy: 8!/(2!*2!), since there are 8! ways to arrange, and two groups of two letters are indistinct (P, O).

Now, I believe I need to multiply this number by the number of ways to break up an eight letter word, and this product should be my final answer. This is where I run into trouble. I can't think of a combinatoric way to figure it out. I can easily see that for one space there are only 7 ways to break up the word, for 6 spaces there are 7, and for 8 spaces there's only one way. But for the other amount of spaces it's more complicated. Any help?

Thanks!

EDIT: Wait, would the number of ways to break up and arrange PORPOISE just be equal to the number of distinct arrangements of POIRPOISE and 7 spaces? i.e. 15!/(2!*2!*7!)?

EDIT 2: No wait, that wouldn't be it, because that sees a difference between P__ORPOISE and P_ORPOISE, when for the sake of this problem there isn't one. But I think I figured it out. So the number of ways to have 7 spaces is 1, 6 spaces is 7C6, 5 is 7C5. So the total number of ways is [8!/(2!*2!)](7C7 + 7C6 + 7C5 + 7C4 + 7C3 + 7C2 + 7C1) = [8!/(2!*2!)]*127 = 10,080 * 127 = 1,280,160. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you required to use all the letters?

Comment: I believe so, though it is not explicitly stated

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely on the right track. For any $8$ letter word, we can break it up into a sentence by adding spaces in between letters. We may put no spaces in the word, or we may place up to $7$ spaces. And there are $7$ places to put a space.

For each spot we can either put a space there, or not put a space there. $2$ options for each $7$ positions which are completely independent from each other. This is a total of $2^7$ combinations.